# Meteor Mongo Shell Version

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongo-shell

I have deployed an application to Meteor's servers, and when I enter the mongo shell of the url I get an error when I try `show dbs`

> 2015-06-01T12:06:57.093-0700 listDatabases failed:{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" } at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:47

I have read that this may be caused by the version of my mongo shell not matching that of mongo, but Im not sure how to get around it.  I can `use` my meteor db (because I know its there without it being listed) and its collections, but when I try to write anything, I get the following error:

`db.users.update({"_id" : "kRmJnwHsRDDXMjpDq"}, {$set : {"admin" : true}})`

> Cannot use commands write mode, degrading to compatibility mode

Answer (score 0):

Not a very helpful answer, but despite error messages in the Mongo shell, the changes were successfully propagated to my application, even though this is the message I received after the `update` command

> Cannot use commands write mode, degrading to compatibility mode
>
> WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0 })

Comment: The "Cannot use commands write mode, degrading to compatibility mode" message is a warning rather than an error. This indicates your `mongo` shell (as reported by `version()`) is connecting to an older MongoDB server (as reported by `db.version()`) and is using older write commands for compatibility. For example, you would see this using a  `mongo` 2.6 or newer shell to connect to a MongoDB 2.4 or older server.